# How to dynamically render a Material UI component by a JSX string

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, babeljs

I want to specify the icon before the names of list items. But the Icon is a component that must be hard coded.

I tried to use babel.transform("function(){return ()}") to help me convert a jsx String to a component. But when I used it, it showed me React is not defined
ReferenceError: React is not defined

I don't know how to deal with the dependencies the components rely on. Please help me.
I used this to make a map

```
let predefined_list = {"Inbox":"InboxIcon", "Message":"MessageIcon", "Settings":"TuneIcon", "Trending":"WhatshotIcon", "Posts":"HomeIcon"}

  let iconList = {}
  for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(predefined_list)) {
    let iconFunctionString = "()=>{return (<" + value + "></" + value + ">)}"
    iconList[key] = eval(babel.transform(iconFunctionString,{presets:["react", "es2017",]}).code)
  }
```

And this one to help me display the items.

```
<List>
          {['Chat', 'Settings', 'Trending', 'Posts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {iconList["Inbox"]()}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
```